# Django: is there a way to count SQL queries from an unit test?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-testing

I am trying to find out the number of queries executed by a utility function. I have written a unit test for this function and the function is working well. What I would like to do is track the number of SQL queries executed by the function so that I can see if there is any improvement after some refactoring.

```
def do_something_in_the_database():
    # Does something in the database
    # return result

class DoSomethingTests(django.test.TestCase):
    def test_function_returns_correct_values(self):
        self.assertEqual(n, <number of SQL queries executed>)
```

EDIT: I found out that there is a pending Django [feature request](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5416) for this. However the ticket is still open. In the meantime is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Since Django 1.3 there is a [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries) available exactly for this purpose.

One way to use it (as of Django 3.2) is as a context manager:

```
# measure queries of some_func and some_func2
with self.assertNumQueries(2):
    result = some_func()
    result2 = some_func2()
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertNumQueries

Comment: if you need `AssertNumQueriesLess` welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089020/1731460

Answer (score 48):

Vinay's response is correct, with one minor addition.

Django's unit test framework actually sets DEBUG to False when it runs, so no matter what you have in `settings.py`, you will not have anything populated in `connection.queries` in your unit test unless you re-enable debug mode. The Django docs explain the [rationale for this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions) as:

> Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration file, all Django tests run with DEBUG=False. This is to ensure that the observed output of your code matches what will be seen in a production setting.

If you're certain that enabling debug will not affect your tests (such as if you're specifically testing DB hits, as it sounds like you are), the solution is to temporarily re-enable debug in your unit test, then set it back afterward:

```
def test_myself(self):
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db import connection

    settings.DEBUG = True
    connection.queries = []

    # Test code as normal
    self.assert_(connection.queries)

    settings.DEBUG = False
```

Comment: Thanks. Toggling DEBUG is precisely what I needed to do. :)

Comment: An additional note: you should really wrap your test code in a try: block, putting settings.DEBUG = False in a corresponding finally: block. This way your other tests won't get "tainted" by the DEBUG setting if this one fails.

Comment: you can use connection.use_debug_cursor = True instead of settings.DEBUG = True. On my opinion it will be more local solution

Comment: why wouldn't you just put settings.DEBUG = True in the setUp() method, and settings.DEBUg = False in the tearDown() method?

Comment: Putting `DEBUG=True` in `setUp()` and `tearDown()` would be ideal if you want the query logging for every test. If you'd prefer to run with production-like DB behaviour for some tests from log queries in only specific tests, then changing the settings is better done in the test function itself. All depends on your testing goal, I suppose.

Comment: @Oduvan For me does not work connection.use_debug_cursor = True with django 1.11.7, just the DEBUG=True .

Comment: This is a very bad way to change the settings (as hinted by @SmileyChris), Django has [a whole bunch of ways to temporarily change settings without contaminating the other tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) (and at least the `@override_settings` decorator has existed since Django 1.4)

Comment: [with self.settings(DEBUG=True): ...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)

Answer (score 33):

If you are using `pytest`, `pytest-django` has [django_assert_num_queries](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#django-assert-num-queries) fixture for this purpose:

```py
def test_queries(django_assert_num_queries):
    with django_assert_num_queries(3):
        Item.objects.create('foo')
        Item.objects.create('bar')
        Item.objects.create('baz')
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want use TestCase (with [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries)) or change settings to DEBUG=True, you can use context manager CaptureQueriesContext (same as [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries) using).

```
from django.db import ConnectionHandler
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext

DB_NAME = "default"  # name of db configured in settings you want to use - "default" is standard
connection = ConnectionHandler()[DB_NAME]
with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as context:
    ... # do your thing
num_queries = context.initial_queries - context.final_queries
assert num_queries == expected_num_queries
```

[db settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/settings/#databases)

Comment: CaptureQueriesContext is a vastly under-valued test context handler.  You can dig into all sorts of things about what the ORM did and why.

Answer (score 8):

In modern Django (>=1.8) it's well documented (it's also documented for 1.7) [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running), you have the method **reset_queries** instead of assigning *connection.queries=[]* which indeed is raising an error, something like that works on django>=1.8:

```
class QueriesTests(django.test.TestCase):
    def test_queries(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        from django.db import connection, reset_queries

        try:
            settings.DEBUG = True
            # [... your ORM code ...]
            self.assertEquals(len(connection.queries), num_of_expected_queries)
        finally:
            settings.DEBUG = False
            reset_queries()
```

You may also consider resetting queries on setUp/tearDown to ensure queries are reset for each test instead of doing it on finally clause, but this way is more explicit (although more verbose), or you can use **reset_queries** in the try clause as many times as you need to evaluate queries counting from 0.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the working prototype of **context manager withAssertNumQueriesLessThan**

```
import json
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext
from django.db import connections

@contextmanager
def withAssertNumQueriesLessThan(self, value, using='default', verbose=False):
    with CaptureQueriesContext(connections[using]) as context:
        yield   # your test will be run here
    if verbose:
        msg = "\r\n%s" % json.dumps(context.captured_queries, indent=4)
    else:
        msg = None
    self.assertLess(len(context.captured_queries), value, msg=msg)
```

It can be simply used in your **unit tests** for example for checking the number of **queries per Django REST API call**

```
    with self.withAssertNumQueriesLessThan(10):
        response = self.client.get('contacts/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Also you can provide exact DB `using` and `verbose` if you **want to pretty-print list of actual  queries to stdout**

Answer (score 4):

If you have `DEBUG` set to True in your `settings.py` (presumably so in your test environment) then you can count queries executed in your test as follows:

```
from django.db import connection

class DoSomethingTests(django.test.TestCase):
    def test_something_or_other(self):
        num_queries_old = len(connection.queries)
        do_something_in_the_database()
        num_queries_new = len(connection.queries)
        self.assertEqual(n, num_queries_new - num_queries_old)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out but strangely enough len(connection.queries) is turning out to be Zero(!) *before and after* the call to the function. I tested it after replacing the function call with a straightforward call to MyModel.objects.filter() and still no luck. 

FYI I am using Django 1.1.

Comment: Update: the mechanism works if I execute the function interactively using iPython. Of course this is against the development database as opposed to the transient test database. Does the discrepancy have something to do with the way Django executes tests in a transaction?

Comment: DEBUG is by default set to False in django tests. This is because you want to test your *live* environment.

Comment: or: `with self.settings(DEBUG=True): ... num_queries = len(connection.queries)`  [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a decorator for that there is a [nice gist](https://gist.github.com/kmike/573536):

```
import functools
import sys
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connection

def shrink_select(sql):
    return re.sub("^SELECT(.+)FROM", "SELECT .. FROM", sql)

def shrink_update(sql):
    return re.sub("SET(.+)WHERE", "SET .. WHERE", sql)

def shrink_insert(sql):
    return re.sub("\((.+)\)", "(..)", sql)

def shrink_sql(sql):
    return shrink_update(shrink_insert(shrink_select(sql)))

def _err_msg(num, expected_num, verbose, func=None):
    func_name = "%s:" % func.__name__ if func else ""
    msg = "%s Expected number of queries is %d, actual number is %d.\n" % (func_name, expected_num, num,)
    if verbose > 0:
        queries = [query['sql'] for query in connection.queries[-num:]]
        if verbose == 1:
            queries = [shrink_sql(sql) for sql in queries]
        msg += "== Queries == \n" +"\n".join(queries)
    return msg


def assertNumQueries(expected_num, verbose=1):

    class DecoratorOrContextManager(object):
        def __call__(self, func):  # decorator
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                handled = False
                try:
                    self.__enter__()
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
                    handled = True
                    raise
                finally:
                    if not handled:
                        self.__exit__(None, None, None)
            return inner

        def __enter__(self):
            self.old_debug = settings.DEBUG
            self.old_query_count = len(connection.queries)
            settings.DEBUG = True

        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            if not type:
                num = len(connection.queries) - self.old_query_count
                assert expected_num == num, _err_msg(num, expected_num, verbose)
            settings.DEBUG = self.old_debug

    return DecoratorOrContextManager()
```