# Avoid making multiple Django database calls

Tags: python, sql, django, database, loops

I would like to query my Django database once and return a Queryset (assigned the name 'codes'), which I can iterate over to obtain each instance's 'internal_code' attribute without making further calls to the database. Here is my code, but I am unsure as to whether I am querying the database each time I use 'get' on the Queryset, and how I can avoid this:

```py
codes = models.RecordType.objects.all()

permanent = sorted([
    (
        codes.get(
            external_code=category.value
        ).internal_code,
        self.labels.get(category, category.name)
    )
    for category in enums.Category
])
```

Comment: I am not a Djangonaut, but to me it is that you make a single query and use the returned queryset

Comment: use `RecordType.objects.values_list('internal_code', flat=True)` to get only the `internal_code` column returned back in list style, then u can `zip` with categories to obtain list of tuples, which is more readable imo.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) operator to `filter` all the `RecordType` with `industry_code` present in the `Category` enum:

```py
codes = (
    RecordType.objects
    .filter(industry_code__in=[c.value for c in Category])
    .only('industry_code', 'internal_code')
)
category_labels = {c.value: self.labels.get(c, c.name) for c in Category}

permanent = sorted([
    (code.internal_code, category_labels[code.industry_code])
    for code in codes
])
```

Using [.only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) in case `RecordType` has a lot of fields that you don't need.

> but I am unsure as to whether I am querying the database each time I use 'get' on the Queryset

Yes. You can chain `.filter()`, `.exclude()`, and other methods that return a queryset without running it; with `.get()` the queryset is evaluated immediately (and every time), returning an instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force an evaluation of the QuerySet you can do this:

`codes = list(models.RecordType.objects.all())`

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is roughly the way to do it, but you shouldn't call `get()` on it all the time. Each time you do it you are making a separate db query.

Django fetches lazily from the database, when you indicate that you want the results. E.g.

```py
# first enable some logging to see the database queries
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'},
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {'level': 'DEBUG',},
    },
})


# No query made
codes = RecordType.objects.filter(
    industry_code__in=[cat.value for cat in enums.Category]
)

# show the query that will be made (roughly)
print(str(codes.query))

# force the queryset to be executed and return all the results.
# the queryset is executed when you iterate over it.
codes_by_industry_code = {
    code.industry_code: code
    for code in codes
}

# now you can set up your list:
permanent = [
    (
        codes_by_industry_code[category.value].internal_code,
        self.labels.get(category, category.name)
    )
    for category in enums.Category
]
```

Now, if you want to be sure that the queries only happen in the right place, you should use a testing tool such as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254170/django-is-there-a-way-to-count-sql-queries-from-an-unit-test) to test your code. That is the only way to be sure going forward that your code is doing what it should be in terms of db queries.